# Chrome asks for permission to open a Sharepoint file in desktop every time. Screenshot attached

Tags: file, google-chrome, popup

Chrome always asks me for permission to [Open Office (desktop)?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9TBK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Found it! Don't remember where.

copy chrome://flags/ & open it in a chrome tab
find #click-to-call-ui 
change the setting from default to disabled
reload chrome
and the popup shouldn't happen anymore